# How to trigger a Tomcat source build using maven?

Tags: maven, tomcat, ant

in my project I would like to compile tomcat 10.0.14 sources from pom.xml of my project. How can I run ant to compile tomcat sources inside maven for my purpose?

I tried with maven-antrun-plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.atlantica</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.14</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-tomcat</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml" target="deploy"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

but I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:3.0.0:run (build-tomcat) on project tomcat: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] /root/sam/tomcat-10.0.14/build.xml:978: Unable to find a javac compiler;
[ERROR] com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
[ERROR] Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
[ERROR] It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64/jre"
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<ant antfile="/root/sam/tomcat-10.0.14/build.xml" target="deploy" />... @ 4:73 in /root/sam/tomcat-10.0.14/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

If I set JAVA_HOME, instead I have other errors:

```
/root/sam/tomcat-10.0.14/java/org/apache/catalina/ant/AbstractCatalinaCommandTask.java:22: error: package org.apache.tools.ant does not exist
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
                           ^
/root/sam/tomcat-10.0.14/java/org/apache/catalina/ant/BaseRedirectorHelperTask.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
public abstract class BaseRedirectorHelperTask extends Task {

/root/sam/tomcat-10.0.14/java/org/apache/catalina/ant/AbstractCatalinaCommandTask.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
    public StringBuilder createQueryString(String command) throws BuildException {
                                                                  ^
```

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: First question: Why? And not using the existing distro?

Comment: I need a modified version of Tomcat to include in my project, so instead of creating one repository for the modified tomcat to build with ant and one for my project to build with mvn, I'd like to have only one repository and build everything with mvn. This because part of my project depends also on the modified tomcat so during the build it must respect a given order between modules

Comment: I asked why ? You say simply a modified version but don't state the reason ... ? Also the output states your java home is not correct etc.

Comment: Modified version with my custom code and hardening from CIS.

Comment: I temporarily resolved using exec-maven-plugin:

```<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals><goal>exec</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>ant</executable>
        <arguments><argument>deploy</argument></arguments>
      </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>```

but I would like to use `maven-antrun-plugin` if possible. Any help?